# Values of x and y such that $a$ and $b$ are orthogonal

Tags: vectors

So I have 2 vectors, $a=(x+y)i+2j+yk$, and $b=3i+(4x+y+1)j+4k$. I need to find the values for $x$ and $y$ such that the two vectors and orthogonal, and parallel. I know that two vectors are orthogonal when their dot product is zero, but solving it doesn't leave me with any way to solve for $x$ and $y$ (i.e. no quadratic or anything of the nature). It is a similar story for the cross product. Any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please use Mathjax.

Comment: Please show your work, you say their dot product is zero and that it doesn't leave you with anything, please show it.

Comment: What did you get for the dot product?

Comment: after doing the dot product and adding all like terms together then setting it equal to zero, i"m left with 11x + 9y +2 = 0

Comment: OK. You’ve got one equation in two unknowns. All this means is that the solution is not unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your vectors are given as

$$ a = (x+y)i + 2j + yk  \\ b = 3i + (4x+y+1)j+k \tag{1} $$

Their dot product is

$$ a \cdot b = 3 \cdot (x+y) + 2\cdot  (4x+y+1) + y    \tag{2} $$

Then the objective like you said is when we set the dot product to zero

$$ 3 \cdot (x+y) + 2\cdot  (4x+y+1) + y  =0 \\ 3x + 3y + 8x +2y+2 +y=0  \tag{3} $$

Now you need to combine like terms

$$ \\ 11x + 6y +2 =0  \tag{4} $$

Your objective is to figure out when this is zero. Let's suppose instead you want to use the cross product.

$$ a \times  b   = \begin{vmatrix} \hat{i} & \hat{j} & \hat{k} \\ (x+y) & 2 & y \\ 3 & (4x+y+1) & 1   \end{vmatrix} \tag{5}$$

Now when we reduce this we get

$$ a \times b = \begin{vmatrix} 2 & y \\ (4x+y+1) & 1  \end{vmatrix} \hat{i} + \begin{vmatrix} (x+y) & y \\ 3 & 1 \end{vmatrix}\hat{j} + \begin{vmatrix} (x+y) & 2 \\3 & (4x+y+1) \end{vmatrix}\hat{k}  \tag{6}$$

Now the last step here is to compute the determinants. The $2 \times 2$ determinant is $ad-bc$

$$ a\times b = (2 - y(4x+y+1) )\hat{i} + ((x+y)-3y )\hat{j} +  ((x+y)(4x+y+1) -6) \hat{k}\tag{7} $$

Now this vector $ a \times b$ will be orthogonal (perpendicular) unless the following is true. If $ a ,b $ are parallel. This implies

$$ \| a \times b\| =0 \tag{8}$$

This implies

$$ a\times b = \hat{0} \tag{9} $$

Which is saying, find where each of those vector entries are zero. That is solve for the zeros of.

$$ -y^{2} -4xy -y +2 =0  \\ x-2y =0 \\ 4x^{2}+5xy+x+y^{2}+y-6 =0  \tag{10} $$

Which is a much worse problem. The vector should be orthogonal in all other cases..

Comment: I guess I was just over complicating it from the start, thank you for the insight though.

Comment: Youre welcome. You still have to consider when theyre parallel.

Comment: Can the same process be used for the cross product? After computing it using the determinate I'm left with different equations for each component of the new vector, a x b = (-4xy - y^2 - y + 8)i - (4x - y)j + (4x^2 + y^2 + 5xy + x + y - 6)k = 0. Could I also solve each of these equations by setting them equal to zero?

Comment: Taking the cross product of two vectors will generate an orthogonal vector. The stuff I did above should generate a line. $ 11x+6y+2=0  $ , this gives $ y = -\frac{-11x}{6}-\frac{1}{3} $ which means $x$ is the intercept. It isn't unique..

Comment: Sorry my wording could have been more specific, I'm all good with the dot product and how the values are not unique given that they're only defined by one equation. My question is can the same process of finding the values for x and y be applied to each component of the normal vector, perhaps through the use of systems of equations, given that I now have 3 separate equations instead of just one equation.

Comment: One second..let me write something..